# Why is Rails 4 not loading a class that Rails 3 would load?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my `test_helper.rb` file I override one method on one model for testing purposes. Let's call it `Foo`.

Suppose I add debug statements as such:

```
#in app/models/foo.rb
class Foo
  puts "loading class Foo from app/models"
  ...
end
```

and:

```
#in test/test_hepler.rb
class Foo
  puts "loading class Foo from test/test_hepler"
  ...
end
```

In in Rails 3, I see on the console:

```
>loading class Foo from app/models
>loading class Foo from test/test_hepler
```

In Rails 4, (even with `config.eager_load = true`) I see only:

```
>loading class Foo from test/test_hepler
```

Why this difference? Also, what is the preferred fix? Simply `require 'Foo'` before I open it for extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change test_helper to do

```
Foo.class_eval do
  ...
end
```

Then rails is forced to load your Foo model (so that it can call `class_eval` on it)

As to why the test initialisation process changed you would have to dig back through the changelogs/commits - there definitely were changes around how/when you app code is preloaded.